# Send message to all users + yourself (Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

client-side javascript file:

```
socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    $(".chat-body").append(msg);
});

$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var msg = $("input[type=text]").val();
    socket.send(msg);
});
```

server-side app.js:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
      socket.broadcast.send(data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      // handle disconnect
    });
});
```

How to send message to yourself too without additional "append"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/How-do-I-send-a-response-to-all-clients-except-sender%3F), it's:

```
// sending to all clients, include sender
io.sockets.emit('message', data);
```

It may also be possible to do:

```
io.sockets.send(data);
```

but it would be doing the same thing, so I'd go with the documented way.

Answer (score 5):

`socket`is the current socket that started event `connection` now you want to emit to all users + yourself use:

`io.sockets.emit('message', msg);`

If you want to send to all sockets except yourself use `broadcast.emit("event", value)`:

`socket.broadcast.emit('event', msg)`

If you just want to answer yourself (socket that initiated event):

`socket.emit('msg_socket', msg);`